# Text in bootstrap card is going outside the box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have this issue that I have made a card in bootstrap, but my text is going outside the picture.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyU66.jpg)

I need it to look like this ( the first example )

[image](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/)

This is what I have been trying

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center padding wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="900ms" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h2>Min profil</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Min profil</a>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Responsive Images**

Create responsive images by adding an `.img-responsive class to the <img> tag.` The image will then scale nicely to the parent element.

The `img-responsive class applies max-width: 100%, height: auto,`

and `display:block` to the image:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 text-center" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="900ms" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
    <div class="card form-group">
        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block form-group" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
            <h2>Min profil</h2>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Min profil</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```